# Ignore day duplicates from timestamps in sqlite table selection

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, duplicates, substring

I have a sqlite database that contains timstamps and tick data. The timestamps contain date and time. For an 'end-of-day' analysis i want to leave out the timestamps duplicates from the same date. It doesn't matter which database row of the date duplicates is selected.

The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE StockQuotes
    (`Timestamps` varchar(19), `Open` float)
;

INSERT INTO StockQuotes
    (`Timestamps`, `Open`)
VALUES
    ('2010-09-16 13:16:22', 33.63),
    ('2010-09-17 13:16:22', 33.53),
    ('2010-09-20 11:26:30', 33.46),
    ('2010-09-20 13:16:22', 33.46),
    ('2010-09-21 11:26:30', 33.76),
    ('2010-09-22 11:26:30', 33.56),
    ('2010-09-23 11:26:30', 33.86),
    ('2010-09-23 13:26:30', 33.86)
;
```

My desired result is:

```
Timestamps              Open
2010-09-16 13:16:22     33.63
2010-09-17 13:16:22     33.53
2010-09-20 11:26:30     33.46
2010-09-21 11:26:30     33.76
2010-09-22 11:26:30     33.56
2010-09-23 11:26:30     33.86
```

or

```
Timestamps              Open
2010-09-16 13:16:22     33.63
2010-09-17 13:16:22     33.53
2010-09-20 13:16:22     33.46
2010-09-21 11:26:30     33.76
2010-09-22 11:26:30     33.56
2010-09-23 13:26:30     33.86
```

I can find the duplicates by this query:

```
SELECT Timestamps, COUNT(SubTS) AS CountSub FROM
(
  SELECT Timestamps,substr (Timestamps,1,10) AS SubTS, Open
  FROM StockQuotes
)
GROUP BY SubTS HAVING (COUNT(SubTS)>1);
```

But finally this does not work:

```
SELECT * FROM StockQuotes WHERE Timestamps NOT IN
(
SELECT Timestamps, COUNT(SubTS) AS CountSub FROM
(
  SELECT Timestamps,substr (Timestamps,1,10) AS SubTS, Open
  FROM StockQuotes
)
GROUP BY SubTS HAVING (COUNT(SubTS)>1)
);
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: You might want to think about fixing the root cause, which *seems* to be a problem with the structure.

Comment: You're right: Fixing the root cause would mean not to let ticks into the database from the same day. But I the idea is to store ticks with different frequencies (daily, weekly etc.) in the database. Filtering these ticks out  of the database by frequency is still a bit too tricky for my level of SQL knowledge. So for now i just use 'end-of-day'.

Comment: No, it means not storing two kinds of facts in one table. If I understand your question correctly, there's only one "open" value per day. You don't seem to have a table that stores that fact. Something like `create table stock_opens (open_date date primary key, open_price decimal(10, 2) not null);` would be a good start.
`

Comment: You just have one "open" value per day if you have a "daily" tick  frequency. If have a "5min" frequency you will get every five minutes an "open" value. That's kind of bizarre but that's how it is handled at stock exchanges. The table above is just a simplified example of the real databse table. The real one has an autoincrement ID as primary key.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the value for "open" can change during the day?

Comment: Yes, you can try this out on Yahoo: [link](https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=BRK-A&a=02&b=17&c=1980&d=02&e=26&f=2016&g=m)

Comment: I don't understand how the tick frequency can change the value a stock opens at. But that's not important. Just ignore me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107433/discussion-between-bebass-and-mike-sherrill-cat-recall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is that you're filtering out all rows with duplicates, so both copies will be missing.

To get one output row for (potentially) multiple input rows, use GROUP BY:

```
SELECT MAX(Timestamps) AS Timestamps,
       Open
FROM StockQuotes
GROUP BY date(Timestamps);
```

The MAX() ensures that you get the latest row in the group.

Comment: This also works fine. Using date() is a good idea, because it avoids the substr(). Do you think MAX() is really necessary? Because the `GROUP BY date(Timestamps)` already truncates the timestamps to dates. So `SELECT * FROM StockQuotes GROUP BY date(Timestamps);` should return the same result. Or am i wrong?

Comment: The MAX() chooses which timestamp from the group to return.

Comment: Thank you very much. I acepted your answer because it is not limited to SQLite syntax and it executes for a result of 1.731 rows in about 0.71secs

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the duplicates by using the following command :

```
delete from StockQuotes where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from StockQuotes group by substr (Timestamps,1,10));
```

[image]
Hope it will work! Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I transformed it into a `select` to avoid the deletion of data. For real data it is quite slower than the slution of CL. It needed 1.17sec to return a result. If you change `substr (Timestamps,1,10)` into `date(Timestamps)` it needed 0.84secs.